# Using a BJT to enhance battery life

Tags: batteries, bjt, led-strip

I have a little project going on, that involves turning on and off a led strip.

The led strip specs :  5M Led SMD 600 Lights
LED : 3528 SMD 
600 Lights, 5m : 120 LED / m

According to [this site](http://www.ledlightsworld.com/page.html?id=38), it will drain 48 watts for the full length.
I am looking to use about 0.5m and power it through a 9V battery. According to [this site](http://www.lednews.org/calculate-power-consume-led-flexible-strip/), the current that the strip will drain will be :

```
Wattage / Voltage = 4,8W / 12V = 0,4 A
```

I am not sure if I should be using the 9V as the denominator, but either way I am looking at about 0.5 Amperes.

**My Question :**

A [9V MN1604 6LR61 alkaline battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery) provides with 560mAh, which gives me roughly 1 hour of battery life.

I know that BJTs can amplify the current, by providing a base current and getting it amplified at the emitter/collector.

Ib will be Ie / hFE , so I am reducing the current I drain from the battery hFE times.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8pDn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(resistors chosen randomly)

So what is wrong with this picture? I must be making a mistake otherwise I am generating the missing power out of thin air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine if you are having an external power supply at the collector of the BJT but in reality you aren't and the current for the base, as you said, would be taken from the battery but so would the current through the collector!

So while the base current is sort of negligible it will still actually be draining more current than originally so there is no point in this being here. And with the voltage drop of the base-emitter junction there may not be enough left for the voltage drops required over the LEDs you have.

While the battery may claim to have a 560mAH, it is not likely that it will actually play out this way, they are quite often conservative with these values and it may actually be higher and last longer than you expect but as mention by Andy, the terminal voltage will droop due to increases in the internal resistance of the battery which again could stop the LEDs lighting up to a satisfactory level.

Comment: `but so would the current through the collector` yes.... I don't know what I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

BJTs can amplify current but they can't conjure energy from nowhere. If you need 500mA then your battery has to supply it and, you might not get the full 60 minutes usage because over that time period the battery terminal voltage will droop/sag and may reach a point where your LEDs get too dim.

Answer (score 0):

In practice you are turning that transistor full on by raising the base more than a diode drop (approx 0.6V) above emitter. You have a simple switch. If you want to use it to modulate current you need much more precise control over the base voltage, almost certainly involving some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Your initial assumption is incorrect, by about an order of magnitude.

The calculation is not

> Wattage / Voltage = 4,8W / 12V = 0,4 A

It is

> 48W / 9V = 5.3A

Your 0.565Ah battery will last, at best:

> 0.565Ah/5.3A = 0.1h, or 6.4 minutes

I believe that battery was characterised at a much lower drain current than 0.565A for 1 hour (I believe typically at 1/10th, but I can find the reference).

When you run a battery at significantly higher drain current that it is characterised at, it will go flat much faster than 6.4 minutes.

Then others have explained why a transistor can't break the laws of thermodynamics, and be a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: The 4,8W was referring to 1/10 of the full length (0.5m vs 5m full length). Thanks for your input though.